# csrftoken cookie not getting delete in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I wanted to delete **sessioid & csrftoken** cookie after Logout for that I used the formal way of deleting cookies in Django.

```
    response.delete_cookie('csrftoken')
    response.delete_cookie('sessionid')
```

Here `sessionid` will be deleted by above code but not the `csrftoken`. Any idea why its happening. I wanted user to have new `sessionid` and `csrftoken` every-time he login to system but if `csrftoken` is not deleted it will remain same every-time.

Answer (score 0):

django set csrf middleware in defalut, it get the 'csrf_cookie' in request and set to response automatically. see the source code in [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py). try to use method 'rotate_token' to refresh 'csrf_cookie'.